# Что хранится в регистре eax в этом коде в самом начале?

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Я начинаю изучать ассемблер. И у меня есть такая программа

```
extern  printf
extern  scanf

SECTION .text
global main
main:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        
        push    n
        push    sfmt
        
        call    scanf
        add     esp, 8
        pop     ebp

startN:   
        cmp eax, dword[n]
        jg done
        mov ebx, 0     

startI:     
        mov dword[i], eax
        mov dword[j], ebx
        mov ecx, dword[n]
        mov dword[x], ecx
        sub dword[x], eax
        sub dword[x], 1
        
        cmp ebx, dword[x]
        jg startJ
        
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        push    pfmt
        call    printf
        add     esp, 4
        pop     ebp
        
        mov eax, dword[i] 
        mov ebx, dword[j] 
        
        
        inc ebx
        jmp startI  
      
startJ:
        mov dword[j], ebx
        cmp ebx, dword[n]  
        je innerLoopDone
        
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        push    pfmt1
        call    printf
        add     esp, 4
        pop     ebp
        
        mov eax, dword[i] 
        mov ebx, dword[j]

        inc ebx
        jmp startJ
        
innerLoopDone:
        mov dword[i], eax
        
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        push    pfmt2
        call    printf
        add     esp, 4
        pop     ebp
        
        mov eax, dword[i] 
        inc eax
        jmp startN

done:   
        mov     eax,0
        ret     

SECTION .data
pfmt:    db " ", 0
pfmt1:   db "*", 0
pfmt2:   db " ",10, 0
sfmt:    db "%d", 0
n:   dd 0
i:       dd 0
j:       dd 0
x:       dd 0
```

Она выводит в консоль символы "*" в следующем формате.

```
Input format: 5
Output format:
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

После того как мы ввели число n программа переходит к метке StartN и первая строчка там `cmp eax, dword[n]`. Команда cmp используется для сравнения двух операндов, но на данном этапе программы мы не занесли значение в регистр eax. В чём смысл такого сравнения?

Answer (score 2):

`eax` заполнен результатом вызова `call    scanf`.

Полагаю, что там получается значение 1 как количество успешно считанных полей (`sfmt:    db "%d", 0` подразумевает ввод одного целого числа)